# How should steering knuckle be attached to suspension arm?

Tags: steering, atv, assembly

I'm trying to assemble a [kids atv](https://www.turbopowersports.com/products/monster-500w-atv) for my son. It's a cheap Chinese model with poor documentation.

I can't figure out how the steering knuckle is supposed to attach to the suspension arm.

It was supplied with 2 washers and a nut and bolt. I assume the washers should go between the bearings and the orange bracket, but the gap is not wide enough to fit both (one on top, one on the bottom).

The bearings are pressed into the knuckle, one on the top which is visible, and a matching one on the bottom. I tried tapping them in further with a rubber mallet and they didn't budge.

[image: 800W kids atv steering knuckle attachment]

It seems like if the parts are assembled any other way, the knuckle will rub directly on the painted surface of the suspension arm.

I could buy thinner washers? But I think this quad was assembled and then disassembled for shipping, so maybe I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it the bearings don't have a spacer which keeps them apart (inside, between the two)? If not, I'd suggest you just get it together however you can, because it wasn't made to last. The knuckle is going to rub on the suspension arm no matter what you do. I doubt there are shoulders in the knuckle either. Your best bet is either to just jam it together or take two Crescent wrenches and pull the tabs of the suspension apart to give you just a bit more room, then slam it together.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks, I just checked and there is a spacer in there of some kind.

Comment: If it is "supposed" to rub, I could but some large brass or plastic washers in there to improve the longevity.

Comment: Is the spacer set to the inside races or the outside races?

Comment: It appears to be sized to the inner races.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your description, I'd suggest the washers should act as spacers for between the bearings and the suspension parts. With the internal spacers between the bearings themselves, the washers should provide a little bit of space so the hub won't rub, or will help minimize any rubbing between the suspension and the hub. There are two main reasons why you want this space: hub to suspension wear; binding while turning. You don't want to get larger washers (in the round direction, not in thickness) because then you are defeating the purpose of getting the hub off of the suspension. If you cannot fit the washers in between, I'd suggest you bend the suspension tabs out just enough to enable you to fit the washers in there. As I stated in the comments, using two adjustable (Crescent) wrenches, prying them apart should give you enough extra room.